Why do I have a CORS issue with "Dio" package despite having set CORS in django backend
I'm developing a Flutter web application that needs to make requests to a Django backend. However, I'm encountering a CORS error when I try to make a request. The error message is:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '<API_URL>' from origin 'http://localhost:63730' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
I've already set up CORS in my Django settings as follows:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

Despite this, I'm still getting the same CORS error. Interestingly, I have other applications built with React and Vue that are able to make requests to the same Django backend without encountering any CORS errors.
I'm not sure why my Flutter web application is encountering CORS errors while my React and Vue applications are not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
NB: I use the Dio package to make the request as so:
class DioWrapper {

 Dio _dio = Dio();

 Dio get dio => _dio;

  DioWrapper() {
    _dio.options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: Uri.encodeFull(
          "https://<my_api_url>/api"),
      receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
      sendTimeout: const Duration(milliseconds: 60 * 1000),
      receiveTimeout: const Duration(milliseconds: 60 * 1000),
      // connectTimeout: 60 * 1000,
      validateStatus: (code) {
        return true;
      },
    );
}

}


And then the request:
final response = await dio.post<Map<String, dynamic>>('/auth/token/',
          data: jsonEncode(
              {Config.username: username, Config.password: password}));
      


Try this.  CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [ "http://localhost:63730"]

Thanks, I already added all the allowed origins but i can't figure out why it still doesn't work. I suspect the dio package, because when i try the http package i don't get that error. but i really need to use Dio

have you passed the content type in the header section?
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
also, You can enable detailed logging in Django to see what happens with the CORS requests.

Yes all the configuration is fine on the django side. I noticed that when i make a request using Dio to any other url, e.g "https://google.com", it generates the same error. So it looks like the problem is with Dio but i can't figure out what's wrong

Why does your base URL start with https (Django) while the error mentions http for flutter? Do you have HTTPS setup for your Django app?

Also django-cors-headers doesn't add proper headers in case of some exception occuring, please check the backend if any error is happening there and if so [edit] the question to add a proper [mre].
